# Changing the path of photos clicked by camera intent

Tags: android

I my developing an app that clicks the photos and it should store the photos in a different folder than the default storage location. please guide me about it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

This is the basic code, please tell me the changes needed to make in it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change default folder location, but you can make copy of image for your use. If you want to change it, then play with system camera. 
You Need to call on activity result and get captured image and store it on any location.
For my case file(image) name is *currenttimestamp.jpg*

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(intent.getData(), "r");
                FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
                File tmpFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"); 
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
```

***EDIT***
tell android you have copied the picture.  This will make the folder show up as a gallery on the users device just pass in the path and mimetype to a media scanner connection.

```
                conn.scanFile(fos..getAbsolutePath(),"image/*");
```

****End edit ***

```
                fis.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

***Edit setup the mediascanner connection ***

```
private static MediaScannerConnection conn;
```

somewhere in onCreate()

```
 conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, this);
 conn.connect();



@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
// now is good time to save stuff in the database because
// the last segment of the uri is the imageId in the mediaStore.
// you can easily pull a thumbnail from the mediaStore with the imageId.
// example of getting thumbnail
//final BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//          bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
//Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
//                          context.getContentResolver(), newImageId,
//                          MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
//                              bmOptions);
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
     //toast ready
     // enable your camera button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyProjectName");

if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
imagesFolder.mkdirs();// <----Do Not Forget this
}

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss_Z");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(currentDateandTime) + ".jpg";
File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);


OutputStream imageFileOS;
try {
    imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
    imageFileOS.write(arg0);
    imageFileOS.flush();
    imageFileOS.close();

    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
            "Image saved: ", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```